# Dúvida em relação a seletores CSS

Tags: css, css3, front-end

comecei a estudar CSS a pouco tempo, e ao analisar o CSS de uma página me deparei com o seguinte trecho:

```
@media (min-width:10px){
body{max-width:none}
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual tipo de seletor é o `@`, e como essa estrutura com parênteses `(min-width:10px)` funciona.

Obrigado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui [Introdução sobre Media Queries](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### De acordo com a W3C

A **regra** `@media`, foi introduzida no CSS2, graças a ela é possivel criar diferentes regras para diferentes tipos de mídias. Isto é, monitores, celulares, TV 4K.

Exemplo: Você pode criar uma **regra** de CSS para Monitores Desktop padrões. Outra regra para impressão ( veja, não é apenas monitores ). Inclusive, regra para Smartphone e Smart TV

### As expressions

Veja a sintaxe

```
@media not|only mediatype and (expressions) {
    CSS-Code;
}
```

Elas basicamente são condições. Isto é, quando usamos `max-width: 480px`, nós dizemos:

**ATÉ** o tamanho `width` de 480px, faça o que está entre as `{ CSS-COde }`

Então de 0px até 480px, ele irá executar o código CSS entre as chaves.

**No seu caso:**

De 10px até o tamanho máximo da tela, ele irá executar o código CSS entre as chaves.

Comment: Mt obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Isso é uma media querie em css, usado para trabalhar com resoluções.

Exemplo no desktop tenho um título com tamanho 50px e no mobile quero que esse título seja menor.

Exemplo:

```css
h1 {
  font-size:50px;
}

@media (max-width:990px) {
  h1 {
    font-size:18px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Teste media queries</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples de entender é que esse comando funciona como se fosse um `if`. Ou seja, se a tela tiver um tamanho mínimo 10px ela vai ocupar o tamanho máximo permitido (`max-width:none`)

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp